# How can a file/script be checked for all the possible errors that might come?

Tags: perl, error-handling, logic

I have a Perl script, and I have to add an error handling there. Like, if any error comes, then do an action. (Can't use exit status !=0).

**How can I check or see what all possible errors could come in the script? Is it feasible?**

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $syat=0;
my $var1=`cat  /abc/mlp/mtn/file1.txt;`;  #file1.txt doesn't exist
`mkdir $var1`;
print "Hello\n";
exit 0;
```

Now let's say file1.txt doesn't exist, so the error would come in assigning to $var1, and the error would also come in "mkdir" command. So, in this way, what all possible errors could be there?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you add some sample code to clarify your question? See [mcve] for more information

Comment: @Håkon Hægland
  Added

Comment: `use autodie` will throw an exception on most errors from builtins. Not backticks, though.

Comment: Wrap code in `eval`, which catches exceptions, then check and handle `$@` (where it places error messages).  Do this with distinct sections of code and be as specific as feasible.

Comment: Stop calling external programs for things that are easy to do in perl. That'll play nicer with error detection things like `autodie`.

Comment: @shawn There are 100's of teams together, and all of their work needs to be integrated. So, it can't be told to everybody to run as per us. That's why some problems like mentioned above arises.

Answer (score 1):

This answer corresponds to the original question:

You can't check all the possible errors automatically. But use [strict](http://p3rl.org/strict) and [warnings](http://p3rl.org/warnings) to prevent the most common ones.

Run the code through `perl -c` to do a check for compile time errors (see [perlrun](http://p3rl.org/perlrun)).

You can also run your code through [perlcritic](https://metacpan.org/pod/perlcritic).

Write tests and use [Devel::Cover](http://p3rl.org/Devel::Cover) to verify you tested all the possible paths of your code.

After you've shown the actual problem, the solution would be not to shell out to do things that you can easily do in Perl. You can then use Perl's exception handling (see e.g. [Try::Tiny](https://perldoc.pl/Try::Tiny)).